# Fixed Header DIV pushed down without margin set

Tags: css, xhtml, header, css-position

I want to use a *fixed header*, with the content behind it. The menu will contain anchor links, so all the content will be in one page.

But, I got stuck at an early stage. I thought this would be no problem, but it seems like the `header` div is snapped to the `content` div somehow. It looks like they have the same margin.

If `position:fixed;` is removed, it looks like it should, but I want it to be fixed.

I really don't understand why this happens, since they're separated from each other. Using something like `margin-top:-100px` doesn't feel right.

Doing this should work without ugly solutions...

CSS:

```
#header {
position:fixed;
width:1200px;
border:1px solid black;
z-index:1;
overflow:hidden;
background-color:white;
}

#menu {
width:100%;
z-index:2;
}

#content {
margin: 100px 0 0 0;
background-color:red;
overflow:hidden;
width:1200px;
z-index: -1;
height:100%;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="header">
 <h1>Header</h1>
  <div id="menu"><ul>
   <li><a href="#works">Works</a></li>
   <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
   <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
   <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
 </ul>
 </div>
 </div>

<div id="content">
  <div id="works" name="works"></div>
  <div id="news" name="news"></div>
  <div id="about" name="about"></div>
  <div id="contact" name="contact"></div>
</div>  

<div id="footer"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `top: 0px;` to your `#header` class

Comment: Thank you! I should have thought about that... xD

Comment: No problem, you must tell that div where you want to fixate him, it cannot read your mind... yet :-))